# What's the difference between database object and cursor object in pysqlite2?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cursor, pysqlite

In Python one may interact with an sqlite database using the `pysqlite2` class.

`from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite`

One way to send commands to the database is through the database object:

```
db = sqlite.connect('mydb.sqlite')
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1(a, b, c)')
```

another way is through a cursor:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2(x, y, z)')
```

Both the ways work and do the job, however I suspect that there are cases where one way is peferred over the another. What are those cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connection.execute` method is an SQLite API extension; it's not specified by DB-API: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/.  It's just shorthand for creating a cursor and calling `execute` on it, returning the cursor.

You shouldn't use it if you want to be sure that your code will work with other DB-API-based database libraries.